Underbraces too narrow when knitting from rmarkdown to word
I want to write equations with underbraces in a manuscript I'm working on. I need the output to be in word, but when I knit to word the resulting output always has the braces too small. I could fix them manually, but  if I ever need to change any details it will be a headache to keep track of.
Here is the result when knitting to word
narrow underbraces
Compared to when knitting to pdf
wide underbraces
This is my .rmd file.
---
title: "underbrace test"
author: "me"
date: "2024-08-30"
output:
  word_document: default
  pdf_document: default
---

$$
\begin{matrix}\text{State} \\ k=\varnothing,\, i=0,\, t\in [t_T, t_{T+1})\end{matrix}\quad \frac{dX_0}{dt} =  - \underbrace{\sum_{j\in \{\text{a}, \text{l},\text{d}, \text{m}\}} \lambda^T_{j} X_0}_{\text{Transition}}
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
\begin{matrix}\text{State} \\ k=\varnothing,\, i=0,\, t\in [t_T, t_{T+1})\end{matrix}\quad \frac{dX_0}{dt} &=  - \underbrace{\sum_{j\in \{\text{a}, \text{l},\text{d}, \text{m}\}} \lambda^T_{j} X_0}_{\text{Transition}}
\end{aligned}
$$

I tried using the \begin{align}..\end{align} environment with bookdown, but the output was exactly the same as using $$\begin{aligned}...\end{aligned}$$. I also tried pasting the code that I have into the word equation editor. That gave an output that is similar to the pdf.
